# Facebook like button and colorbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, colorbox

Hello i want to add the facebook like button in colorbox windows i tried everything but it doesn't work. What can i do ? it isn't possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked the [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/) site?

Here is a sample code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"><iframe>
```